# Tensorboard error: Failed to launch TensorBoard (exited with 1). Contents of stderr:

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

Can someone help me with this error. I tried uninstalling Tensorflow Tensorboard and reinstalled still I am facing the issue.

```
ERROR: Failed to launch TensorBoard (exited with 1).
Contents of stderr:
2021-05-29 16:11:25.794509: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_110.dll
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\shara\anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "c:\users\shara\anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\shara\anaconda3\Scripts\tensorboard.exe\__main__.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "c:\users\shara\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\main.py", line 46, in run_main
    app.run(tensorboard.main, flags_parser=tensorboard.configure)
  File "c:\users\shara\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\absl\app.py", line 300, in run
    _run_main(main, args)
  File "c:\users\shara\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\absl\app.py", line 251, in _run_main
    sys.exit(main(argv))
  File "c:\users\shara\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\program.py", line 276, in main
    return runner(self.flags) or 0
  File "c:\users\shara\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\program.py", line 292, in _run_serve_subcommand
    server = self._make_server()
  File "c:\users\shara\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\program.py", line 472, in _make_server
    deprecated_multiplexer,
  File "c:\users\shara\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\backend\application.py", line 145, in TensorBoardWSGIApp
    experimental_middlewares,
  File "c:\users\shara\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\backend\application.py", line 253, in __init__
    "Duplicate plugins for name %s" % plugin.plugin_name
ValueError: Duplicate plugins for name projector
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be possible that you still have 2 versions of tensorboard installed.

Here is a script, which will check if there are some problems with your tensorboard and may give you some instructions on how to fix it:
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tensorflow/tensorboard/master/tensorboard/tools/diagnose_tensorboard.py

I would give it a try.